# show all buckets from aggregation within a single _type where one index contains multiple _type with same field names

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index named "electronics". I created two _type in index i.e "mobiles", "laptops" which have common field name "screensize".

Since I need to show facets for all the terms present in the fields, I am using aggregations to generate the terms and its facets.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "screensize",
        'min_doc_count': 0,
        'size': 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the response I am getting all the screensizes with _type of mobiles as well as laptops(Since lucene treats same field names from different types as single field.). I only need the terms present in mobiles even if their count is 0.

I thought about doing a filtered query for mobiles _type before doing aggregations, but the results were still the same.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "mobiles"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "screensize",
        'min_doc_count': 0,
        'size': 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I could possibly get only the terms from a single _type for a particular field?

Comment: Why don't you simply run your query on `/electronics/mobiles/_search`? That will de facto only focus on the `mobiles` document types.

Comment: Yes I do it like that only. I use elasticsearch-py, the query that we do is.
`es = client.search(index='electronics',doc_type='mobiles',body=body)`

where body is the query that I posted above.

Comment: Then if you already specify `doc_type='mobiles'` you're guaranteed that only `mobiles` document are taken into account by your aggregation.

Comment: [{u'key': 2.4, u'doc_count': 353}, {u'key': 2.2, u'doc_count': 23}, {u'key': 2.6, u'doc_count': 22}, {u'key': 6.0, u'doc_count': 22}, {u'key': 5.2, u'doc_count': 14}, {u'key': 5.3, u'doc_count': 14},  {u'key': 4.6, u'doc_count': 6}, {u'key': 5.9, u'doc_count': 6}, {u'key': 5.1, u'doc_count': 4},{u'key': 27.0, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 29.46, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 31.75, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 33.78, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 35.2, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 35.5, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 35.56, u'doc_count': 0}, {u'key': 15.6, u'doc_count': 0}] . I am getting all

Comment: Not easy to tackle without seeing some sample documents...

Comment: this is screen shot of my code  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85mKQ6Z8btzelp0bDc5YXRtd0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried without `min_doc_count`? Do you have the same results?

Comment: i cannot use without min_doc_count = 0. since i need counts for zero terms from only the same doc_type that is why this problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suggesting another approach using a `terms` aggregation with a `script` instead of `field` like this. The script will only return the value of the screensize if the `type` of the document is `mobiles` and `null` instead. This should work, try it out:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_field": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc._type.value == 'mobiles' ? doc.screensize.value : null",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For this to work you also need to make sure that [scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)